# ROLLBACK in TRIGGER causes Msg 3609

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, transactions, rollback

I have an Items table & an Items_Log table to log all changes to the Item table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
  [item_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [item_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [item_desc] [varchar](250) NULL,
  [modified_by_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [modified_date] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items_Log] (
  [item_log_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [item_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [item_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [item_desc] [varchar](250) NULL,
  [modified_by_id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [modified_date] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Updates to the Items table are performed in a SPROC.  ([modified_by_id] intentionally commented out, as noted below)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pUpdateItem]
  @ItemID INT,
  @Name VARCHAR(100),
  @ByID INT
AS
  UPDATE [Items] SET
    item_name = @Name,
    --modified_by_id = @ByID,
    modified_date = GETDATE()
  WHERE item_id = @ItemID;
GO
```

There is a Trigger on the Items table that logs the old data when it gets updated in any way.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tItemsUpdate] 
   ON [dbo].[Items] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (UPDATE(modified_by_id) AND UPDATE(modified_date))
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [Items_Log]
        SELECT * FROM Deleted
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('[modified_by_id] and [modified_date] must be updated.', 16, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

To test the trigger, [modified_by_id] is commented out so that RAISERROR gets called.  I am getting 2 errors back:

```
Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Procedure tItemsUpdate, Line 15
[modified_by_id] and [modified_date] must be updated.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pUpdateItem, Line 5
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

The 1st error is obviously the error that I want to see, and the transaction correctly rolls back.  But I really want it to exit without throwing the 2nd error, because it displays for the user like this.

So, according to suggestions I have seen elsewhere, I tried doing a Try...Catch in the SPROC, along with a formal declaration of the Transaction and the Rollback there (and taking the Rollback out of the Trigger).  It looked like this in the SPROC:

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE [Items] SET
      item_name = @Name,
      --modified_by_id = @ByID,
      modified_date = GETDATE()
    WHERE item_id = @ItemID;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Now the Update does not occur, but I get no error message at all.  Not even the one from RAISERROR.

I wish I could simply surpress "Msg 3609".  That would make everything work the way I want it too.  But at this point I'll take almost any solution that works.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx

or

```
BEGIN CATCH  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT, @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(100); 
    SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Comment: Ok, I am getting the Error info that way, but now it isn't throwing the error back to my Class. I guess I could do RAISERROR again with the captured values?

Comment: Yes, you may raise new error, probably adding some info.

Comment: Yeah, it is going to be a little bulky if I have to do this in almost every SPROC, but this is basically what I have now:

BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT`
`  DECLARE @ErrorState INT`
`  DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(100)`
  SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
  SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
  SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  
  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH'

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with it to see if I could even do it without declaring variables, but it doesn't look like it. This is messy, but at least it works.  Thanks!