# How to make ROLLBACK function in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger that contains a `ROLLBACK` function. I want to rollback the transaction when customer order qty of Nugget more that stock we have. If that happens, the message will appear like `RAISERROR` function.

Any reply would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate. You're not getting the error, but this will show you the `RollBack` in a trigger. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756545/rollback-in-trigger-causes-msg-3609?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest not putting rollback in your trigger code ever. It will cause nothing but pain. Any operation that causes a trigger to fire has an implicit transaction. If you have an explicit transaction in your application code (or stored proc) and you rollback that transaction in a trigger your trancount will be off and you will have some serious challenges. If you want a trigger to check some conditions you should use RAISERROR in your trigger and let the exception bubble up.

Comment: @WEI_DBA okay i'll check.

Comment: @SeanLange, so what possible method could be use to `rollback` the transaction?

Comment: Again, I would not rollback a transaction in the trigger. Instead use raiserror. This will cause an implicit transaction to rollback and if you have an explicit transaction you can catch the exception and handle it gracefully. Not sure how your system works but I would rather have an item become backordered instead of failing to place the entire order. Then communicate with the customer that the quantity ordered is out of stock but we can get it to you by xxx date.

Comment: @SeanLange so the point is, there is no way i'm to use `rollback`? alongside using trigger? with criteria mention above? btw sorry if i can't completely understand your reply

Comment: If you put a rollback in your trigger and your calling code also has a transaction there will no longer be an active transaction when control is returned to your calling code. This will likely cause you to need to deal with an entirely different problem.

Comment: The difference is begin transaction > insert > trigger function > return error > rollback transaction with error handling (try/cstch) vs begin transaction > insert > trigger rollback >.your initial transaction for the insert is now rolled back.